# How to update a column with input value from a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA macros and was looking to create something to take the input from A1 and add it to B1, then overwrite A1 and add that to B2 and so forth. A1 would act as an input box while the B column would record what was entered.

I came across something from a different forum post and tried to edit it to fit what I was trying to do but it doesn't seem to work and comes back with a compile error about expecting the end of the statement.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    
        b = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & b).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range"(A1").Value
          
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That code is fine as posted (except for the typo `"(A1")`).

Comment: @SJR Thanks much, edited the typo and it works.